# Run feeds importer from outside the site

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I have a Feeds importer that's running periodically (with cron) using "Feeds Fetcher Directory" fetcher. Now I need to run the importer **on demand** from other app outside the site. Is there a way **to just run** the importer (not cron) in a similar way as cron does? (going to some url)

I'm using Drupal 7.53.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 7.x-2.0-beta3, Feeds has Drush support. You could use the following command to trigger an import (where 'my_importer' is the machine name of your importer):

```
drush feeds-import my_importer
```

If the importer is attached to a content type, specify also the feed
node with the option '--nid':

```
drush feeds-import my_importer --nid=2
```

Note that a source for the importer in question must exist*. So you need to have gone through the import form at least once.

You could write a shell script that executes the drush command and that is triggered when the url is requested.

---

*The drush command 'feeds-import' has more options, allowing you to perform an import even when no source was created yet. But I don't think that applies in your situation. See https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/feeds/feeds-import for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good option i didnt know about. Sadly in my case Drupal is running on Windows without drush.